# image based count down clock

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a count down clock which works absolutely fine. Now the question is can I display images as digits instead of html. I cant seem to figure out the logic how would I approach it. I really dont want to use a plugin for this so that is really not an option.

and the JS for the clock is this

```
setInterval(function(){
    var future = new Date("Jan 20 2014 21:15:00 GMT+0200");
    var now = new Date();
    var difference = Math.floor((future.getTime() - now.getTime()) / 1000);

    var seconds = fixIntegers(difference % 60);
    difference = Math.floor(difference / 60);

    var minutes = fixIntegers(difference % 60);
    difference = Math.floor(difference / 60);

    var hours = fixIntegers(difference % 24);
    difference = Math.floor(difference / 24);

    var days = difference;

    $(".seconds").text(seconds + "s");
    $(".minutes").text(minutes + "m");
    $(".hours").text(hours + "h");
    $(".days").text(days + "d");
}, 1000);

function fixIntegers(integer)
{
    if (integer < 0)
        integer = 0;
    if (integer < 10)
        return "0" + integer;
    return "" + integer;
}
```

I have stored the images in an array which is this

```
var linkCons = 'http://soumghosh.com/otherProjects/Numbers/'

var num = [];
var linkCons = "http://soumghosh.com/otherProjects/Numbers/";
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    num.push(linkCons + "nw" + i + ".png");
}
```

Thanks to stack overflow folks helping me cleaning the array. Really appriciate it

And here is the working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/wvbPq/3/

Comment: could use a sprite with numbers 0-9 and setup spans with classes that set background position based on number  `num_1{ background-position: 0 -10px}` parse date/time into individual numbers and set classes accordingly

Comment: I get that. Because I am looking at few plugins which actually do that. Is it absolutely not doable with individual images?

Comment: yes...sprite more efficient though. Only one http request and are guranteed it is in page so don't have flicker getting a new image. Not hard to create a spite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using only one sprite image and this bit of code I created:

[image]

```js
jQuery(function($) { // DOM ready shorthand

  // CLOCK
  
  // Just a date in the future... Say 5 days from now
  var fut = new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 5); 
  
  // Number splitter
  function intSpl(i) {
    i = Math.floor(i);
    return [Math.floor(i / 10), i % 10]; // 37=[3,7] // 5=[0,5] // 0=[0,0] 
  }
  
  var obj = {}; // {d:[7,7], h:[1,9], .....}

  function drawTime() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var dif = now < fut ? Math.floor((fut - now) / 1000) : 0;
    obj.s = intSpl(dif % 60);
    obj.m = intSpl(dif / 60 % 60);
    obj.h = intSpl(dif / 60 / 60 % 24);
    obj.d = intSpl(dif / 60 / 60 / 24);

    for (var key in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) { // get el ID number (0,1)
          $('#' + key + i).css({
            backgroundPosition: -obj[key][i] * 50
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
  drawTime();
  setInterval(drawTime, 1000);

});
```

```css
#clock span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 85px;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/uBTxTTD.jpg');
  background-position: 0 0;
}

#clock span:nth-child(even) {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<div id="clock">

  <span id="d0"></span>
  <span id="d1"></span>

  <span id="h0"></span>
  <span id="h1"></span>

  <span id="m0"></span>
  <span id="m1"></span>

  <span id="s0"></span>
  <span id="s1"></span>

</div>
```

### To explain the idea:

- Create elements, each will hold a one digit of the current 2 digits value;
- Set a common bg image to all `span`s in CSS
- Every second move each element's background-image left by `-(witdh * number)` px

While the listed above seems logic, the first problem you can see here is how to retrieve separately a JS time number (1 or 2 digits) keep leading *zero* if needed, and reference each digit to target the right element in HTML?

**Let's start by splitting numbers:**

`35 == 3, 5   ///   0 == 0, 0  // this is an example of what we need.`

```
var n  = 35;        // Set any 1 or 2 digit number.
var n1 = ~~(n/10);  // 3 //// ~~ "Double Bitwise NOT"
                                 // just instead of parseInt(time/10, 10).
var n2 = n%10;      // 5 //// %  "Mudulus operator" (reminder).
```

<sup>[Example playground](http://jsbin.com/eZewOWu/1/edit)</sup>

**JS Grouping**

Now, **how to group** this two separated digits and say: "Hey you two are for my clock seconds!" ?
By simply putting them into an array! `[3, 5]`, and for we'll have also minutes, hours and day - let's simply put all those arrays into an `Object` and assign a **Key Name** which will result in having an object like:

```
obj = {d:[7,4], h:[1,9], m:[2,9], s:[0,7]}
```

**Reference to HTML**

Having that Object and knowing that inside an `for...in` loop we can retrieve the Key name and the array value like eg: `obj['d'][0] === 7` `obj['d'][5] === 4`

means that we'll need a `for` loop to retrieve the `0` and `1` to get the values in our array positions `[pos0, pos1]`
all inside a `for...in` loop that will get the KEY names : `d, h, m, s`

*2pos x 4keyNames = 8 elements iterations/second*

means that now we'll be able to target an ID element eg: `#s0` and `#s1`
and all we need now is to retrieve the value and animate that element background by
 `-width * digit`

Comment: @ Roko-- Is there a way we could make it work in IE8? It doesnt work in IE 8

Comment: @soum sure! Just instead of jQuery v. `2.0.2` use the latest `1`. 
`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>` From v `2` jQuery dropped support for older browsers.

Comment: @Roko--just did that but still seeing the same problem. I also think in reality I wont be able to update the jQuery version since the site where it has to live has some dependency with a lower version. I think it is still running on 1.5. Very unfortunate but thats what it is

Comment: @soum Works beautifully with `1.5` **IE8**

Comment: @soum Please, also, wrap the code I provided into **document.ready** function!! `jQuery(function($){ /*HERE*/ });`

Comment: @Roko--I did that and its still not working. Very strange. Is there a way I can share the entire document with you?

here is the link to the prototype
http://soumghosh.com/otherProjects/clock.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40788/discussion-between-roko-c-buljan-and-soum)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Do you have any solution to my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43655965/flip-clock-image-based-count-down-timer-using-css-and-jsvascript

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's another way that you may use to solve the same problem. Here are the steps. Firstly I wrote one CSS class selector for each image position.

```
.list-group-item .digit-display{
  display:inline-block;
  width:50px;
  height:85px;
  background:url('http://i.imgur.com/uBTxTTD.jpg');
}

.position-0 {
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.position-1 {
  background-position: -50px 0px !important;
}
```

Then I wrote a JavaScript function which takes a digit as an input and return the CSS class selector for that digit as below.

```
  displayDigit(digit) {
    const baseSelector = "digit-display position-";
    return `${baseSelector}${digit}`;
  }
```

Finally this function is called inside the JSX element as below.

```
<span className = {this.displayDigit(remainingTime["h"].charAt(0))}></span>
```

That solved the issue.

However, if someone really needs to go with the jquery based approach specified above, we can still condense down that same code as below.

```
  secondsToTime(secs) {
    let hours = `${constants.ZERO}${Math.floor(secs / (60 * 60))}`.slice(-2);

    let divisorForMinutes = secs % (60 * 60);
    let minutes = `${constants.ZERO}${Math.floor(divisorForMinutes / 60)}`.slice(-2);

    let divisorForSeconds = divisorForMinutes % 60;
    let seconds = `${constants.ZERO}${Math.ceil(divisorForSeconds)}`.slice(-2);

    let obj = {
      "h": hours,
      "m": minutes,
      "s": seconds
    };
    return obj;
  }

handleFlipClockImage = () => {
     var myObj = this.secondsToTime(seconds);

     Object.keys(myObj).forEach(key => {
     let obj = myObj[key];
     var digits = obj.split(constants.EMPTY_SPACE_CHAR);
     digits.forEach((digit, index) => {
        jquery(`#${this.state.label}${key}${index}`).css({backgroundPosition: -digit*50 });
        });
     });
}
```